# Adjusting constrast when scanning using SANE

Tags: scanner, sane

I just did a scan with my new Brother multifunction CP-7065DN printer using the SANE frontend gscan2pdf. The paper in question was handwritten, and the scan was too light. When I reprinted the scan, it was significantly lighter than the original; too light.

I'm interested in ways to fix this problem. Two different approaches come to mind:

1. Fix the problem by adjusting the settings in SANE (or it's
   frontends).
2. Post process the scan to improve the contrast, using only free software that runs on Unix-like platforms, naturally.

The other possible option that comes to mind, namely adjust the hardware settings, don't seem to be an option with this Brother printer, and would be off-topic on this site anyway.

As far as 1 goes, maybe there are settings even in gscan2pdf that would fix this problem, but I could not make sense of them. I quite like gscan2pdf. It is nice and simple and does what I need, which is to scan to PDF for A4 sized paper. However, I'd consider using another SANE frontend. As for 2, I came across the unpaper project whose purpose is to post-process scans, but I could not figure out if improving contrast was something it would do.

If someone knows how to do this, I'd appreciate a pointer, preferably with a little detail. A mini-tutorial, as it were.

Comment: There's this app: https://github.com/Flameeyes/unpaper.

Comment: One thing to check: Open one of the scanned images in GIMP. Go to Colors -> Levels. The "input levels" shows you which values (brightnesses) are used. You'll see one peak for the paper color, it should ideally be at the far right. There should be a broader peek for the ink color, hopefully fairly far to the left (at least for black ink). You can also adjust the three sliders underneath to fix the contrast. BTW: Right of "reset channel", there are buttons for linear and log scale; look at both if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was originally motivated by a handwritten letter, which scanned very poorly with gscan2pdf - the handwriting was very faint in the scan.

I found a simple remedy to this. By default gscan2pdf has `Scan mode` set as `24bit Color[Fast]`, whatever that means. At any rate, changing that to the `Black&White` option dramatically improved the sharpness of the handwriting of my (B&W) letter. Since basically everything I scan is a B&W document, I think I will use this setting all the time. I don't see why having this settings should make so much difference though.

The other two settings I've changed from the default is the `Scan resolution` (under `Mode`) from 200 to 300. I'm guessing that is dpi. I'm not sure what the optimal resolution is, but 200 seems low. Additionally, I've set `Paper size` (under `Geometry`) to A4.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a scanner hooked up to my Fedora 19 laptop so I cannot give you tried and verified advice, so these are bits and pieces of things that I've been able to find that may help you out.

#### Tip #1

I found this thread titled: [Re: How do I brighen up scan in gscan2pdf](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1681579) which offered this approach via the `gscan2pdf` GUI.

> Click the Scan button and set following properties:
>
> - use "Lineart" setting
> - use 300 dpi
> - use "Threshold" set to 50
>
> Then on the first tab, click the "Options" button
>   - Black Threshold 0.48
>   - White threshold perhaps 0.9
>
> When saving document, in the compression menu, choose PNG.

#### Tip #2

Try using the application `unpaper` to cleanup your scans. I'm not sure how much improvement it can do for scans that are already too light, but it might be worth a look.

- https://github.com/Flameeyes/unpaper

There's a frontend tool that makes use of `unpaper` called `scantailor`. Both should be in your distro's repos. I also found a tutorial video that shows how to make use of `scantailor` to clean up the digitizing of a book, along with another which is just a generic tutorial.

- [DIY Book Page Scan Tailor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ngj_MB2MlDM)
- [Scan Tailor tutorial](http://vimeo.com/12524529)

[image: ss #1]

#### Tip #3

I found this tutorial titled: [Linux, OCR and PDF: Scan to PDF/A](http://www.konradvoelkel.com/2013/03/scan-to-pdfa/) which might provide some methods for improving your scans.